# Perpetual Motion and Thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation, perpetual-motion

How does the second law of thermodynamics disprove all [perpetual motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_motion) machines?

Comment: because a perpetual machine can decrease overall entropy which is forbiden by the second law.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the second law of thermodynamics forbid the possibility of perpetual machine of the second kind?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/217792/)